# How to import custom module in julia

Tags: julia

I have a module I wrote here:

```
# Hello.jl
module Hello
    function foo
        return 1
    end
end
```

and

```
# Main.jl
using Hello
foo()
```

When I run the `Main` module:

```
$ julia ./Main.jl
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Hello not found in path
 in require at ./loading.jl:249
 in include at ./boot.jl:261
 in include_from_node1 at ./loading.jl:320
 in process_options at ./client.jl:280
 in _start at ./client.jl:378
while loading /Main.jl, in expression starting on line 1
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**This answer has been OUTDATED. Please see other excellent explanations.**

===

You should `include("./Hello.jl")` before `using Hello`

Comment: What is the signigicance of `using` then? I thought this kw would include the module for me...

Comment: @dopatraman `using` is to introduce the names of a module into current scope, while the module itself won't be `include()` automaticlly (except for those in "LOAD_PATH")

Comment: If you have definitions inside a `module`, you also need to export them.

Comment: in newer Julia versions you just need include. No need of "using" anymore

Comment: @LucasCavalcantiRodrigues, Not quite. A side effect of `include`ing a module contained in a file is that the file contents are evaluated in the global scope. That's not always (if ever) desirable. See: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/code-loading/

Comment: It seems that `using .Hello` is needed for my installation of Julia 1.7.2? Or is this that the  `using .Hello` is not needed anymore?

Answer (score 72):

There is a new answer to this question since the release of Julia v0.7 and v1.0 that is slightly different. I just had to do this so I figured I'd post my findings here.

As already explained in other solutions, it is necessary to include the relevant script which defines the module. However, since the custom module is not a package, it cannot be loaded as a package with the same `using` or `import` commands as could be done in older Julia versions.

So the Main.jl script would be written with a relative import like this:

```
include("./Hello.jl")
using .Hello
foo()
```

I found this explained simply in [Stefan Karpinski's discourse comment](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/including-modules-in-julia-v0-7/12559/6) on a similar question. As he describes, the situation can also get more elaborate when dealing with submodules. The [documentation section on module paths](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/modules/#Relative-and-absolute-module-paths-1) is also a good reference.

Comment: The second link is dead. Information as of this writing is available here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/#Modules-and-files-1

Comment: I'm using Julia 1.2 and it appears it is not necessary to use the `using .name` statement anymore. Executing `include("./name")` is enough to import the file and its functions into the current script.

Comment: @theferrit32 `include` and `using` differ essentially. Much like C/C++, `include` brings the source code of the specified file into the calling file as if one had written the other file directly within the calling file.

`using` on the other hand is not concerned with files (unless a file with the same name is found in the `LOAD_PATH`). It is used to import symbols of a specific module into the calling module. One may define multiple modules per file, and each module would need to call `using` or `import` on the sibling modules in order to access their functions.

Comment: I found that this solution creates additional problems. Types, generated in "Hello.jl" are different to the ones you use in e.g. "main.jl", even if you imported/use them (see e.g. https://discourse.julialang.org/t/error-with-modules-sharing-types/37119)

Answer (score 32):

**EDIT**: Updated code to apply post-v1.0. The other answers still have a  fundamental problem: if you define a module and then `include` that module definition in multiple places, you will get unexpected hard-to-understand errors. @kiliantics' answer is correct as long as you only `include` the file once. If you have a module that you're using across multiple files, make that module [into a package](https://pkgdocs.julialang.org/v1/creating-packages/), use `add MyModule`, and then type `using MyModule` in as many places as you want, letting Pkg handle module identity for you.

---

Though 张实唯's answer is the most convenient, **you should not use `include` outside the REPL** (or just *once* per included file as a simple practice to organize large modules, as in the first example [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/)). If you're writing a program file, go through the trouble of adding the appropriate directory to the LOAD_PATH. Remy gives a very good explanation of how to do so, but it's worth also explaining why you should do so in the first place. (Additionally from the docs: `push!(LOAD_PATH, "/Path/To/My/Module/")` but note your module and your file have to have the same name)

The problem is that anything you `include` will be defined right where you call `include` *even if it is also defined elsewhere*. Since the goal of modules is re-use, you'll probably eventually use `MyModule` in more than one file. If you call `include` in each file, then each will have its own definition of MyModule, and even though they are identical, these will be different definitions. That means any data defined in the `MyModule` (such as data types) will not be the same.

To see why this is a huge problem, consider these three files:

types.jl

```
module TypeModule
struct A end
export A
end
```

a_function.jl

```
include("types.jl")
module AFunctionModule
using ..TypeModule
function takes_a(a::A)
    println("Took A!")
end
export takes_a
end
```

function_caller.jl

```
include("a_function.jl")
include("types.jl")  # delete this line to make it work
using .TypeModule, .AFunctionModule
my_a = A()
takes_a(my_a)
```

If you run `julia function_caller.jl` you'll get `MethodError: no method matching takes_a(::A)`. This is because the type `A` used in function_caller.jl is different from the one used in a_function.jl. In this simple case, you can actually "fix" the problem by reversing the order of the includes in function_caller.jl (or just by deleting `include("types.jl")` entirely from function_caller.jl! That's not good!). But what if you wanted another file b_function.jl that also used a type defined in `TypeModule`? You would have to do something very hacky. Or you could just modify your LOAD_PATH so the module is only defined once.

EDIT in response to xji: To distribute a module, you'd use `Pkg` ([docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/packages/)). I understood the premise of this question to be a custom, personal module. It's also fine for distribution if you know the relative path of the directory containing your module definition from each file that needs to load that module, e.g. if all your files are in the same folder then you'd just have `push!(LOAD_PATH, @__DIR__)`.

Incidentally, if you really don't like the idea of modifying your load path (even if it's only within the scope of a single script...) you could symlink your module into a package directory (e.g. `~/.julia/v0.6/MyModule/MyModule.jl`) and then `Pkg.add(MyModule)` and then import as normal. I find that to be a bit more trouble.

Comment: That actually doesn't seem to be portable if the program is to be distributed and run on other users' systems right? In this way every user will have to modify their environment variable just to run every new Julia program on their system?

Comment: Does this answer apply to Julia 0.7+?

Comment: I agree with you, the accepted answer seems the easiest way to solve this issue but comes at a cost. I have created a discussion on the topi. feel free to contribute. 
https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-import-a-local-module-into-another-in-different-file/42058

Answer (score 21):

This answers was originally written for Julia 0.4.5. There is now an easier way of importing a local file (see @kiliantics answer). However, I will leave this up as my answer explains several other methods of loading files from other directories which may be of use still.

---

There have already been some short answers, but I wanted to provide a more complete answer if possible.

When you run `using MyModule`, Julia only searches for it in a list of directories known as your `LOAD_PATH`. If you type `LOAD_PATH` in the Julia REPL, you will get something like the following:

```
2-element Array{ByteString,1}:
 "/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/local/share/julia/site/v0.4"
 "/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/site/v0.4"
```

These are the directories that Julia will search for modules to include when you type `using Hello`. In the example that you provided, since `Hello` was not in your `LOAD_PATH`, Julia was unable to find it.

If you wish to include a local module, you can specify its location relative to your current working directory.

```
julia> include("./src/Hello.jl")
```

Once the file has been included, you can then run `using Hello` as normal to get all of the same behavior. For one off scripts, this is probably the best solution. However, if you find yourself regular having to `include()` a certain set of directories, you can permanently add them to your `LOAD_PATH`.

**Adding directories to `LOAD_PATH`**

Manually adding directories to your `LOAD_PATH` can be a pain if you wish to regularly use particular modules that are stored outside of the Julia `LOAD_PATH`. In that case, you can append additional directories to the `LOAD_PATH` environment variable. Julia will then automatically search through these directories whenever you issue an `import` or `using` command.

One way to do this is to add the following to your `.basrc`, `.profile`, `.zshrc`.

```
export JULIA_LOAD_PATH="/path/to/module/storage/folder"
```

This will append that directory onto the standard directories that Julia will search. If you then run

```
julia> LOAD_PATH
```

It should return

```
3-element Array{ByteString,1}:
 "/path/to/module/storage/folder"
 "/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/local/share/julia/site/v0.4"
 "/Applications/Julia-0.4.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/share/julia/site/v0.4"
```

You can now freely run `using Hello` and Julia will automatically find the module (as long as it is stored underneath `/path/to/module/storage/folder`.

For more information, take a look at [this](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/modules/) page from the Julia Docs.

Comment: That actually doesn't seem to be portable if the program is to be distributed and run on other users' systems right? In this way every user will have to modify their environment variable just to run every new Julia program on their system?

Comment: @xji No; this is just for loading libraries from Julia and this works exactly like C, Python etc. If you want to run a Julia program, `julia myprogram.jl` (just like `python myprogram.py`). However if you want to *import* a library into a Julia program, Julia needs to know where to look - just like GCC/Clang needs to know where to look for non-system C/C++ header files, or Python needs to know where to look for non-system or user-installed packages. There is no portable alternative for *any* language. If you don't want to modify your path, install the package with the Julia package manager.

Comment: for Julia >= 0.7, see @kiliantics answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52298205/2822346. Basically, you need to add a `.` to make  relative import after the `include` statement

Answer (score 3):

Unless you explicitly load the file (`include("./Hello.jl")`) Julia looks for module files in directories defined in the LOAD_PATH variable.

See [this page](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/modules/).

Answer (score 3):

I have `Julia Version 1.4.2 (2020-05-23)`.  Just this `using .Hello` worked for me.
However, I had to compile the Hello module before just `using .Hello`. It makes sense for both the defined and using scripts of `Hello` is on the same file.

Instead, we can define `Hello` in one file and use it in a different file with `include("./Hello.jl");using .Hello`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access function foo when importing the module with "using" you need to add "export foo" in the header of the module.