# Creating and using a custom module in Julia

Tags: module, julia

Although this question has been asked before, it appears that much has changed with respect to modules in Julia V1.0.

I'm trying to write a custom module and do some testing on it.  From [the Julia documentation on Pkg](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/Pkg/#Developing-packages-1), using the `dev` command, there is a way to create a git tree and start working.

However, this seems like overkill at this point.  I would like to just do a small local file, say `mymodule.jl` that would be like:

```
module MyModule

export f, mystruct

function f()
end

struct mystruct
  x::Integer
end

end # MyModule
```

It appears that it used to be possible to load it with

```
include("module.jl")
using MyModule
```

entering the `include("module.jl")`, it appears that the code loads, i.e. there is no error, however, `using MyModule` gives the error:

```
ArgumentError: Package MyModule not found in current path:
   - Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("MyModule")` to install the MyModule package.
```

I notice that upon using `include("module.jl")`, there is access to the exported function and struct using the full path, `MyModule.f()` but I would like the shorter version, just `f()`.

My question then is: to develop a module, do I need to use the Pkg `dev` command or is there a lighter weight way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import custom module in julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200025/how-to-import-custom-module-in-julia)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to use a local module, you must prefix the module name with a `.`.

```
using .MyModule
```

When `using MyModule` is run (without the `.`), Julia attempts to find a module called `MyModule` installed to the current Pkg environment, hence the error.

Comment: Hi, sorry for bringing up old thread. I'm assuming I suppose to run this after `include("mymodule.jl")`? How can I use `MyModule` without `include`? The thing is there are functions I don't want to export and by including it, I can still access it with `Main.MyModule.function_I_dont_want_to_import`.