# Does importing custom modules in Julia results in having to reference them relative to Main?

Tags: julia

I found [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37200025/how-to-import-custom-module-in-julia) on importing modules in Julia, but I'm getting a somewhat strange behavior, and I was wondering if this was normal.

My files `tst.jl` and `Tmp.jl` are:

```
tst.jl
    1 include("./Tmp.jl")
    2 import Main.Tmp
    3 
    4 Main.Tmp.greetings()

Tmp.jl
    1 module Tmp
    2     export greetings
    3     function greetings()
    4         println("Greetings Earthlings")
    5     end                                                                              
    6 end
```

But my `tst.jl` cannot see `Tmp` unless its under `Main`.

My `LOAD_PATH` also looks kind of strange:

```
julia> LOAD_PATH
3-element Array{String,1}:
 "@"      
 "@v#.#"  
 "@stdlib"
```

Is this normal, or could something be wrong with my installation?

I tried using JuliaBox and got

```
julia> LOAD_PATH
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 "/opt/julia-0.6.2/local/share/julia/site/v0.6"
 "/opt/julia-0.6.2/share/julia/site/v0.6"
 "/home/jrun/.julia/v0.6"
```

However, thats v0.6, while I am using Julia v1.0.2 on OpenSUSE Tumbleweed.

I downloaded the binaries from https://julialang.org/downloads/ and manually moved libs and all into corresponding root directories.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But my tst.jl cannot see Tmp unless its under Main.

no, you should use relative module paths, see [Relative and absolute module paths](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/manual/modules/#Relative-and-absolute-module-paths-1)

```
tst.jl
    1 include("./Tmp.jl")
    2 using .Tmp
    3 
    4 greetings()
```

> My LOAD_PATH also looks kind of strange:

don't worry, that's normal in Julia1.0 era. X-ref: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/interpreting-load-path-in-1-0/13529

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated